# DSx - graphlab module

Tags: python, graphlab, data-science-experience

I want to use graphlab in a DSx notebook.
I have installed the module with:
!pip install --user --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/my_license/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz

But running `import graphlab` fails with error:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-8-18109c918415> in <module>() ...
----> 4 import graphlab

/gpfs/fs01/user/sc9b-86b94c11f9c6d7-2ca36d25e590/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/__init__.py in <module>()
     48 from graphlab.util import set_runtime_config
     49 
---> 50 import graphlab.connect as _mt
     51 import graphlab.connect.aws as aws
     52 from . import visualization

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

What am I missing? Any hints?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that something went wrong during installation. To get more output from the pip install attempt, execute

```
!cat $LOG_FILE
```

in the same notebook kernel. Maybe there are error messages that explain the problem. If the kernel is no longer running, you will still find log files in `$SERVICE_HOME/logs/`. Or you can delete the user-installed Python packages with `!rm -rf ~/.local`, restart the kernel, and re-install from scratch.